# Accessing users groups through attributes / foreign keys in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to access my users groups in Django, but keep getting

```
auth.Group.None
```

as the result.

When in the django shell I'll first create a group, then a user and add the user to the group. After this, I try to print the users groups, like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

Artists = Group.objects.create(name="Artists")
Artists.save()
Rihanna = User.objects.create_user(username="Rihanna", password="newpassword")
Rihanna.save()
Artists.user_set.add(Rihanna)
# Save both of them again just to double check
Rihanna.save()
Artists.save()

# Now try to access Rihanna's groups through her attributes:
print Rihanna.groups, Rihanna.groups.name
```

and the results are

```
>>> auth.Group.None None
```

What I'd like to happen is for it to print the groups name.

I know I can query the members of a group by the filter and get commands, but I'd like to access the groups straight through a users attributes/foreign keys. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You added user to group in group object, but your user object does not have update state for this.

Try access groups like this:

```
print Rihanna.groups.all()
```

or add group in user model:

```
Rihanna.groups.add(Artists)
```